# Eggplant/Sensetalk Search for string then grab the next word

Tags: eggplant

I'm learning Eggplant.  I would like to some string for a specific string and then grab the text following that string.  For example, I want to get the version number for the following string since it changes.

```
This is some log statement telling me the that the version=1.2.3
```

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 3):

You could extract the version number from that line of text using the following code.

```
set line = "This is some log statement telling me the that the version=1.2.3"
set versionIndicator = "version="

if versionIndicator is in line
    set indicatorPosition = word number containing versionIndicator within line
    set versionNumber = word indicatorPosition of text 
    delete versionIndicator from versionNumber --removes "version="
end if
```

If you know it will be the last word on the line you can address it directly instead of calculating it's position first.

```
if version indicator is in line
    set versionNumber = last word of line
    delete versionIndicator from versionNumber
end if
```

Answer (score 1):

A pretty effective way of doing this kind of task is to use the FoundImageRectangle property of an OCR search to create a SearchRectangle.

```
Put ImageRectangle (text:"version=", ValidWords:"*") into VersionTag //Since the string we're searching for isn't a dictionary word the ValidWords:"*" can help out.

Put ReadText ((right of VersionTag, top of VersionTag +5, x of RemoteScreenSize(), bottom of VersionTag), ValidCharacters:"1234567890.") into VersionNumber //Limiting the available characters for the read should improve reliability of the result.
```

That will end up getting you all the text to the right of the string "version=". If there's some other limit you could use, like the edge of a UI element, then the X of that could be used instead of the RemoteScreenSize.

Answer (score 0):

Can't we use this simple mentioned code for validating any data present in UI Using

```
//SearchRectangle concept 

set DATA to "ABCCordinates"

**Put ImageRectangle("ImageLocation")into SR_Searchdropdown
Set SR_Diff_SearchOption to ((0,0,0,0))
If ImageFound(text:DATA,SearchRectangle:SR_Searchdropdown+SR_Diff_SearchOption, waitFor:100) then
    Click FoundImageLocation()**
```

Explanation of Code

1. In the first step, I have set the variable to pass the parameter.
2. Using step2 I have placed the base image location

   I have calculated the base coordinates and target Image location coordinates using **Log ReadText(0,0,0,0)**, and then I have subtracted from the base and target coordinates I got respected coordinate which I have paste in the 3 steps for finding out the Data.
3. Step using if `ImageFound` will validate that the data is present and in the next step, it will highlight that data using click `FoundImageLocation()`.

I think this can be the easiest way to find the data using the Search Rectangle coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way of doing this would be by using split in my opinion.

```
set logText = "elling me the that the version=1.2.3"
put logText split by "=" into lst
put item 2 of lst into Version
Log Version
```

Explanation:
Line 2 splits the text with "=" delimiter thus creating a list with 2 items. Whatever is on the left hand side of = goes into item 1 and the right hand part goes into item 2
Item 2 is now our version